# Не работает Sphinx Yii2

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Не работает поиск русских слов

Конфиг

```
source nahodu_announcement
{
  type                                    = mysql
  sql_host                                = localhost
  sql_user                                = root
  sql_pass                                = 
  sql_db                                  = myDb
  sql_port                                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
  sql_query_pre                           = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query_pre                           = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
  sql_query                               =  \
  SELECT id, title \
  FROM announcement WHERE status='enabled'
  sql_ranged_throttle                     = 0
  sql_query_info                          = SELECT id, title FROM announcement WHERE id = $id
}

index nahodu_announcement
{

  source                  = nahodu_announcement
  path                    = /var/www/nahodu.local/frontend/runtime/sphinx/announcement/index
  docinfo                 = extern
  mlock                   = 0
  morphology              = stem_ru
  min_word_len            = 1
  charset_type            = utf-8
  #charset_table          = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+A8->U+B8, U+B8, U+C0..U+DF->U+E0..U+FF, U+E0..U+FF
  #charset_table           = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
  # min_prefix_len        = 0
  min_infix_len           = 1
  # prefix_fields         = filename
  # infix_fields          = url, domain
  enable_star             = 1
  html_strip              = 1
}


searchd {
    listen = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
    log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    pid_file = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
    read_timeout = 5
    max_children = 30
    max_matches = 1000
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 0
    unlink_old = 1
}
```

Делаю запрос к базе

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM announcement WHERE title LIKE  %Про%';
```

возвращает пустой массив, если передаю слово на английском, то все работает. Когда ищу с консоли, то возвращает знаки вопроса вместо слов.
Тут явно проблема с кодировкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вы уверены в том что
1. БД имеет тип кодировки UTF-8
2. В конфиге Сфинкса был прописан тип кодировки UTF-8
3. В конфиге Сфинкса была прописана правильная charset_table для UTF-8
4. Запрос должен приходить тоже в UTF-8

Comment: я ж выложил конфиги, все в utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что я не добавил `START=yes` в `/etc/default/sphinxsearch`